# Rails: html_escape isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

For some reason html escaping isn't working in my Rails application. Even if I write something like

```
<%=h '©äö' %>
```

it isn't converting any of the characters to HTML entities.

I have no clue what the could be. It worked always fine and now just suddenly it don't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be related to your document encoding type?

Comment: I have tried changing it from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google sitemap [requires fully escaped URLs](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35653), so in this case you need to escape all special and international characters.

This [**htmlentities** library](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/) does that for you.

I even wrote a little wrapper in the `application_helper.rb`:

```
def html_entity_escape(s)
  require 'htmlentities'
  @html_coder ||= HTMLEntities.new
  @html_coder.encode(s)
end
```

Comment: `HTMLEntities.new.encode("©äöá", :named)` I did this to escape á too. Thank you for the tip of this gem.

Answer (score 8):

`ö` and `ä` are valid characters in HTML. There is no need to escape them, even if there are HTML entities for them. These entities are convenience, not necessity - as long as the declared encoding (HTTP headers) and the actual character encoding matches, there is no problem if they occur literally.

The only characters that always must be escaped are `<`, `>`, `&` and `"`, like in XML.

Comment: OK, didn't know that only <, >, & and " are escaped because in other languages those kind of functions usualy escape all characters that have an equivalent HTML entity. Is there a way to do that in Rails?

Comment: Whydo you want that? It would give no benefit, increase HTML source size and is a pain in the a** for people that want to work with the HTML source code for some reason. I'd prefer the actual characters in the source code wherever possible, I think Rails does the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that h only replaces the HTML special characters <, >, & and ". Please have a look on documentation of Rails's [ERB::Util.html_escape](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#M000315) which is behind the h function.